# Output incorrect: determine if three digits are unique and add up to a given sum

Tags: c

> ### The Problem:
>
> Given a goal sum and three positive digits, determine if the three positive digits are unique and sum up to the goal.
>
> ### The Input:
>
> Input will begin with a single, positive integer, *n*, on a line by itself.  On the next *n* lines will be a single positive integer representing the goal sum followed by three single positive digits, each separated by a single space.
>
> ### The Output:
>
> For each line of input, determine if the three digits sum to the goal and are unique.  Output “Proper triplet” on a line by itself if so, or “Not a good triplet” on a line by itself if not.

```
int main()
{
   FILE *ifp;

   //Open file
   ifp = fopen("kakuro.in", "r");

   int numcases, index;

   fscanf(ifp, "%d", &numcases);

   //Go through each case
   for (index=0; index<numcases; index++){

    int target,n1,n2,n3, total;

    //Read in data and allocate to variables above

    fscanf(ifp, "%d%d%d%d", target,n1,n2,n3);
    total = n1+n2+n3;

    //add numbers together
    if (total == target){
        //check for duplicate numbers
        if ( n1 != n2 && n2 != n3 &&n1 != n3)
            printf("numbers pass test\n");
        else printf("numbers are repeated,test failed\n");
    }
    else {printf ("The total does not sum to the target\n");
    }
   }

   fclose(ifp);
   return 0;
}
```

Sample input file:

```
20
19 4 7 8
10 1 9 6
14 3 8 3
2000000000 1 2 3
16 4 4 8
16 8 4 4
16 8 5 3
16 3 5 8
16 3 8 5
16 5 3 8
16 5 8 3
16 8 3 5
6 1 2 3
24 7 8 9
3 1 1 1
27 9 9 9
1 1 1 1
9 9 9 9
22 6 7 9
12 3 4 5
```

Comment: Please don't put your test data in images; paste it into your question.

Comment: thanks for the feedback

Comment: Please read "[ask]", then [edit] your question to include a problem statement:  What does your program do, and what did you expect to happen instead?  (Also, change your title to reflect the problem.  I just paraphrased the assignment, which isn't really good enough.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the inputs:

```
fscanf(ifp, "%d%d%d%d", &target, &n1, &n2, &n3);
```

Also your error messages don't match those in your question, but the above is your main issue.

Answer (score 1):

References are needed in function call

```
fscanf(ifp, "%d%d%d%d", &target, &n1, &n2, &n3);
```

You need to give address of the variable where you want to store value.